# How to adjust the blinking cursor location in a text input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a form, and I added padding to the placeholder so it wasn't pushed up against the box it sits in. I am trying to do the same for a text input cursor. When the user clicks in the text input, I want the blinking cursor to have padding so it isn't pressed against the input box it sits in. If you see the picture I added, you can see the blinking cursor pressed against the border. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJD3k.png)

Answer (score 0):

try adding to the class in css

```
text-indent: 20px;
```

Comment: this fixed it. Thank you. I knew it was something simple I just couldn't get google to turn up any results

Answer (score 0):

Applying padding to your `textField` should solve this problem. Try the code below,

```css
.input-field{
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input class="input-field" placeholder="First Name"/>
</body>
</html>
```